# preg_match compilation failed: missing parenthesis

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

preg_match says i'm missing a parenthesis. But where? :(

```
preg_match('/^(Lam)\/(\d+)\.(\d+) \(Trent/', $string, $matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with backslashes within regex. Try the following code instead:

```
<?php
// Notice the double backslashes
preg_match('/^(Lam)\\/(\d+)\\.(\d+) \\(Trent/', $string, $matches)
```